# which technologies shall I use to offer an out-of-box server installation

Tags: java, php, mysql, windows, macos

I want to build a client-server architecture software, and I want the server component can be easily installed by average people on their Windows or Mac OS X operating systems.

The server-side:
1. contains a self-running web server
2. hosts a web-based administrator site to manage business data and master data
3. provides API endpoints (in JSON) over WIFI
4. has sqlite 3 or MySQL database to hold business data
5. the data volume is low, the

The client-side are mobile applications which talk with server via API endpoints over WIFI.

I started thinking about Java, as JVM is installed on almost every computer, but what about the web-server and database? In a sense, as I use MAMP on my Mac a lot, I like the approach of this nice product, easy install, one click to launch all services.

Can anyone point me a possible direction?

Comment: Wrap it all up, make it cross platform and shoot it. Job done. Which direction you're concerned of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have suggested MySQL.  That sounds fine to me.

I would suggest Tomcat as a pretty widely used web-server.